# How to add image as watermark in microsoft document using Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

[image: Image Link]

I have added watermark image in this document manually. Is there any way to add image as watermark in Microsoft document using Java or JavaScript(jquery) programming language ?

Comment: Take a look at the Apache POI for word. http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model/XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.html  - you have a method called createWatermark it should do the trick

Comment: Apache poi createWatermark method only works for text.

Comment: Work around with POI... I've never done what you need so I can only guide you. This answer that modifies the image attributes seems a good way : https://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/884537-create-watermark-excel-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at *GroupDocs.Watermark for Java* API to add the image watermark as well as text watermark to the MS Office document formats using Java. For more details, you can visit the API home: https://products.groupdocs.com/watermark/java.

Answer (score 0):

[Free Spire.Doc](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-for-java.html#.YZNRBBpByUk) for Java can help you easily add image as watermark into word.
The following is code.

```
    import com.spire.doc.Document;
    import com.spire.doc.FileFormat;
    import com.spire.doc.PictureWatermark;

    public class AddImageAsWatermark {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.loadFromFile("sample.docx");

        PictureWatermark picture = new PictureWatermark();
        picture.setPicture("fire.jpg");
        picture.setScaling(50);
        picture.isWashout(false);
        doc.setWatermark(picture);

        doc.saveToFile("AddImageWatermark.docx", FileFormat.Docx_2013);
     }
    }
  }
```